# check simple js function exists from other js file does not work

Tags: jquery, function, typechecking

I have two jquery scripts from different files : `file1.js` and `file2.js`

- `file1.js` is not necessary included in my page.
- `file2.js` call a function from `file1.js` or call an other function (if `file1.js` does not exists).

So I need to check if the function `sendSearch` exists.
file1.js

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // ...
    function sendSearch(currentObject, output_data = true, output_count = true) {
      // ...
    }
    // ...
  });
});
```

file2.js

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Search button and queries
    $(".my-button").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      if (typeof $.fn.sendSearch !== undefined && $.isFunction($.fn.sendSearch)) {
        alert("sendSearch !!!");
        // sendSearch(...);
      } else {
        alert("No sendSearch");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

This code does not work, how can I fix the function checking ?

Comment: `sendSearch()` is buried deep within the scope of the document.ready (in fact two, but that can be fixed later). As such there's no way for an external script to access it. You need to declare it at a higher scope, accessible to both scripts.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan if it´s not possible, where can I put `sendSearch()` function to be checked ?

Comment: Outside of document.ready

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan It does not work for me as well. The unique way I found all the time is transform my script in jQuery plugin to use his functions.